# Prolog predicate return true and false

Tags: prolog

I've set out to solve a logical problem found in a kid game just to prove myself that some problems has more than one solution.

The game is as follow, you have multiple kind of candy, and with some partial instruction you need to find the correct set of candy.

Candies are defined by kind and color.

Insctuction are on the following form

- 6 candy
- 4 cake
- 3 red, at least one blue, one green and one orange
- as much blue as there is green
- as much licorice as there is fish

Here are my facts

```
bear(bear_yellow).
bear(bear_green).
bear(bear_orange).
bear(bear_red).

licorice(licorice_red).

cake(cake_blue).
cake(cake_red).
cake(cake_green).
cake(cake_yellow).

fish(fish_yellow).
fish(fish_orange).
fish(fish_red).
fish(fish_green).

jelly_bean(jelly_bean_red).
jelly_bean(jelly_bean_green).
jelly_bean(jelly_bean_pink).
jelly_bean(jelly_bean_purple).
jelly_bean(jelly_bean_blue).

blue(cake_blue).
blue(jelly_bean_fish).

yellow(bear_yellow).
yellow(cake_yellow).
yellow(fish_yellow).

red(bear_red).
red(licorice_red).
red(cake_red).
red(fish_red).
red(jelly_bean_red).

green(bear_green).
green(fish_green).
green(jelly_bean_green).

orange(bear_orange).
orange(fish_orange).

pink(jelly_bean_pink).

purple(jelly_bean_purple).

is_positive(NUMBER) :- NUMBER > 0.

contains_at_least_one(CANDYS, TEST) :-
    count(CANDYS, TEST, NB),    is_positive(NB).

count([], _, 0).
count([X|TAIL], F, RES) :- call(F,X) ->  count(TAIL, F, ACC), RES is ACC+1;  count(TAIL, F, RES).

contains_at_least_one_list(_, []) :- true.
contains_at_least_one_list(CANDYS, [TEST|TEST_TAIL]) :-
    contains_at_least_one(CANDYS, TEST),
    contains_at_least_one_list(CANDYS, TEST_TAIL).
```

I think there is something fishy with the predicate `contains_at_least_one_list` but i can't found what's the problem.

With the previous definitions here is a question that is not correct

```
contains_at_least_one_list([bear_red, fish_orange], [red, orange])
%which return true and false
```

Here is a print screen from the trace

[image: Trace]

I'didn't practice prolog for 10 years, and it's obvious to me that that the question is very vague, if you can come up with a better question or even a link to a better stated question feel free

Comment: A complete problem statement will help us better if the code is suspect.

Comment: I just want to point out that your database is a hot mess of denormalized data. I can't really tell what is up but it just doesn't look too useful. Without complete problem statement it is impossible to suggest improvements.

Comment: Well, you haven't checked for additional facts (same number of ble and green, etc), so that is why you get `true`. Also, consider using cut operator (`!`) to specify there is a unique solution.
Btw, you don't need to specify truthfulness in `contains_at_least_one_list(_, []) :- true.`, just make it a fact.

Answer (score 1):

Many Prolog predicates will "return true and false". For example:

```
?- member(a, [a, b, c]).
true ;
false.
```

The `false` doesn't mean that `a` is not a member of the list `[a, b, c]`. It means that after Prolog derived once that `a` is a member of `[a, b, c]` (that's the `true` answer), you asked it if there is *another way* of deriving the fact that `a` is a member of `[a, b, c]`. There isn't, so the *second* answer is `false`. But this second answer is independent of the first one. It does not override or invalidate it. `a` is a member of `[a, b, c]`.

Some queries can succeed several times:

```
?- member(a, [a, b, a, c]).
true ;
true ;
false.
```

Here there are two occurrences of `a` in the list, so if you ask for an alternative after the first answer, Prolog will be able to find a second one. But not a third one, so the third answer is `false`. Again, this is nothing to worry about. A final `false` after a success doesn't mean "there is no successful answer". It just means "there is no *other* successful answer".